# ASP.NET MVC: input-validation-valid applied style not working

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I found this [article](https://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/validating-user-input-in-aspnet-web-pages-sites) and I know its for webpages and not for MVC. My question or problem is the following. If a user provides the correct input for a textbox, I want to change its background-color to green, I did it with red for errors, that works. But the example shown in this article does not seem to work in my application and I did not find another example that made it work. So here is my CSS-Style that I tried to apply:

ErrorAndValidationHighlighting.css:

```
 .input-validation-error {background-color: #ffb3b3;}
 .input-validation-valid {background-color: #6BEF66;}
```

The TextBoxes in my view all look like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AdditionalComment)
```

As I said above, it works for the errors like it should, background-color changes to red and is displayed, but for valid input it does not work at the moment, so maybe you guys see what mistake Im doing or what is missing to make this work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Edit: Please post the code of what you did :)

Comment: @M.Arendsen - OP has posted the code - its the `.css`

Comment: I think you need to be using a `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` where you'd like your validation errors - then MVC will do the rest. Also, in your ViewModel for what you're displaying you should set some attributes to complement the MVC validation

Comment: It's a bit unclear what other HTML you're using (and if you've using the `ValidationMessageFor()` helper as I suggested previously). If you could post a bit more code it would be useful. Here's a great tutorial on validation in MVC: https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model

Comment: Hello @GeoffJames thanks for your quick response and your advice. I tried it with ValidationMessageFor(), but as expected that only brings up a message, but does not change the background-color of a valid field.

What I did, I checked that no other CSS-File, or in the Views any class is applied that contains a defintion for .input-validation-valid, so its not overwritten by another CSS-File.

Comment: @RawMVC fair enough - I probably didn't read properly first time round. Can we see the markup of where/how you're trying to set the background color of the field(s)?

Comment: Their is no `class="input-validation-valid"` applied to inputs. Its `class="valid"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Once again you solved my problem and you're completely right, I changed my class to valid and the fields work like they should, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Please apply this code and check the result

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AdditionalComment,new  {@class="input-validation-valid"})
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your example and it works. Now Im a bit confused, since @Stephen Muecke said above that there is no such class as input-validation-valid.

Comment: Edit: I have to correct myself at this point, the solution of you does not work was intended, because if validation fails, the background-color stays green instead of changing to red. So @Stephen Muecke was right, its just valid and it works with that.